# Is there a way to know when someone imports an attached vcard?

Tags: import, email-attachments, vcf-vcard

I'm developing a program that sends vCards as an attachment via email. I'd like to be able to tag a user in my db when they import the attachment.

One example is a user gets an email and their client is Outlook. When they  import it, is there a way to wrap it with a callback to the server

Does anyone know if there is a way to do that, or is this just not done for security reasons?

Comment: I don't think this is possible from the perspective you're approaching it.  You want to 1) intercept/catch any user who imports a vCard/attachment into their local contacts 2) update a database when 1) occurs?  Step 1) is going to update a local file on the user's local storage.  Unless you have explicit monitoring/logging on, I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: Hi Grav, I think you may be right. What I wanted to do it know when someone clicked on a link to import a vcard. The card will be generated by my server, when the sender updates their online account. One thought is the email could be a link to a web page where the user imports the card. That way I'd know someone has accepted the card. I was trying to see if there was a way to know if they imported an attachment.

Comment: If there is a link to a page you own (and code is maintained by you), then sure... you could 'generate and download a vCard,' and in that same web script, update a database.  However, your question states, _"as an attachment via email,"_ which is significantly different from what you just described.

Answer (score 0):

Per Gravity:

If there is a link to a page you own (and code is maintained by you), then sure... you could 'generate and download a vCard,' and in that same web script, update a database. However, your question states, "as an attachment via email," which is significantly different from what you just described. – gravity